# USB bit locker require recovery key id doesn't ask for bit locker password

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I have a 32GB SanDisk USB drive that was encrypted using BitLocker drive encryption, but recently the drive has been opening without requiring me to enter the BitLocker passcode.

Help! What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Does it open and show files on any computer you connect it to without asking for the password, or just a specific computer (or computers)?

If the drive only opens on certain computers and still asks for a password on others, that probably means that you told the computer to remember this password (for BitLocker, this means the computer probably has a security chip called a "TPM" which is required for a computer to remember a BitLocker password).

When the USB drive is connected to the computer that it automatically opens on, right-click on the drive icon in your File Explorer and select BitLocker Encryption Options and change it not to remember the password.

If the drive opens and shows files on all computers, you may have turned BitLocker encryption off on the drive, and you'll just need to encrypt it again.

Comment: Exactly when i connected USB drive to any computer it ask for recovery key , when i go to manage bit locker the Turn off option is disable.

Comment: If you're getting the prompt on other computers, then it just means that this computer has a TPM chip and it is enabled and you've told it to automatically decrypt the drive when you insert it.